# Howto make :active event stay active after click

Tags: html, css

How can I make this div stay active after the click?

I tried looking it up but saw nothing that applied to textarea transitions

CSS:

```
.comment-box:active {
    /* Settings for Transition */
    height:100px;
    /* Transition: Basic */
    transition-duration:0.8s;
    transition-timing-function:ease;
    /* Transition: Chrome+Safari */
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.8s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function:ease;
    /* Transition: Mozilla */
    -moz-transition-duration:0.8s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function:ease;
    /* Transition: Opera */
    -o-transition-duration:0.8s;
    -o-transition-timing-function:ease;
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea type="text" validation="required" name="comment" placeholder="type a comment here..." maxlength="500" class="comment-box"></textarea>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep :active css style after clicking an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738219/how-to-keep-active-css-style-after-clicking-an-element)

Comment: thanks for not flagging it, I said that I couldn't find anything that would work for me. also thanks Adrift and @Johansrk for your suggestions, I'll try them out :D

Comment: :visited
{
css declarations;
}