# using javascript to make a light switch

Tags: javascript

I want to using javascript to make a light switch.
When the background color is:
"white" => turn on
"black" => turn off

**Question: My code can turn off the light, but I don't know how to turn it on.**

**I have a idea to the last, but it dosen't work. How to fix it?**

Here is my code.
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <mate charset="utf-8" />
    <title>light Switch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lightSwitch.css" />
</head>

<body>
<!--
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="lightOn">turn on</a>
</br>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="lightOff">turn off</a>
</br>
-->
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="lightSwitch">The switch</a>

    <script src="lightSwitch.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#lightSwitch{
    width: 300px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -15px 0 0 -152.5px;
}
```

javascript

```
function lightSwitch(){
    var light = document.getElementById("lightSwitch");
    var BGcolor = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
    if (BGcolor != "black"){
        light.innerHTML = "The light is open! Click here to close.";
        light.onclick = function(){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "Black";
            light.innerHTML = "The light is close! Click here to open.";
        }
    }
}
lightSwitch();
```

**I have a idea, look:**

```
function lightSwitch(){
    var light = document.getElementById("lightSwitch");
    var BGcolor = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
    if (BGcolor != "black"){
        light.innerHTML = "The light is open! Click here to close.";
        light.onclick = function(){
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "Black";
            light.innerHTML = "The light is close! Click here to open.";
        }else{
            light.onclick = function(){
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }
        }
    }
}
lightSwitch();
```

Comment: Do you want to use plain javascript? If not, look at toggleClass in jQuery it'll do the trick.

Comment: `"black"` does not equal `"Black"`

Comment: I would suggest to toggle a `class` on the body element instead of a `style` property. A class is more flexible (you can change more than one attribute) and the naming is up to you (no problems with `Black` vs `black` vs `#000` etc.)

Comment: @johanthuresson Yes, I want to use plain javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified the code. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/0o4L2mbo/1/)

### HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div><button id="lightSwitch">Switch</button>
```

### JS:

```
var swit = document.getElementById('lightSwitch');
var container = document.getElementById('container');
swit.onclick = function(){
    var color = container.style.backgroundColor;
        if(color === 'white'){
            container.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        }else{
            container.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Your demo is work. And do you have another way to finish this  function? Such as define a CSS class?

Comment: What do you mean by finish this function?

Comment: Sorry, my English is not very well. I mean can  you use CSS to achieve "light switch"?

Comment: It doesn't look like you can do it with CSS alone. There is the selector :active that on 'click' will do what you want.. but once the click is finished it will revert to whatever it was before the click. I found a post that mixes more css than js and uses the :active. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738219/how-to-keep-active-css-style-after-clicking-an-element (but they use jquery in this post ).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is way too complicated. Define a CSS class and assign the class as required.

I created a [demo](http://codepen.io/gapcode/pen/azKeVW) (at Codepen) to demonstrate my thoughts. Hope this helps.

The JavaScript part as preview:

```
document.getElementById('switch').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (this.classList.contains('off')) {
    // switch on
    this.classList.remove('off');
  } else {
    // switch off
    this.classList.add('off');
  }
});
```

By toggling the class you can achieve a lot more than just changing one property, as shown in the demo.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have no idea to use CSS class.