# Is there a CSS code for 'double click' element or another way to solve this?

Tags: css

I have two texts that are hidden at first `display:none` and if I click on object1 a text below it will appear, if I click on object2 another text will appear, but the first text disappears.

Then I can click on object1 again to make the second text disappear and the first appear.

But I can't get the texts to `display:none;` again because I have to have an object selected now after clicking on one of them.

My question now is if there is a CSS code like:

If object1/object2 is clicked twice, text1 AND text 2 will be `display:none` again like in the beginning.

Comment: It's good practice to give us a sample of your relevant code (HTML and corresponding CSS).

Comment: The type of interface you are describing sounds like something called an "accordion." You can see an example of one [here](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion). I think instead of checking for a double click, you should instead check that an active item is clicked, as the example in that link shows. A double click is 2 clicks made rapidly right after the other. As @Jhecht mentioned, you should show us your code.

Comment: CSS has no click (nor doubleclick) notion. It has other notions like checkedness and focuseness which you can you to get similar results. Since you didn't include your code, it's not clear which approach you are using, so your question is off-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle radio input using CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36162805/1529630)

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery:

```
$('#obj1').dblclick(function(){
    $('text2').toggle();
});
```

-- EDIT to better version --

```
<div class="textToHide">Text1</div>
<div class="textToHide">Text2</div>
<div id="myDblClickObj">Click me to hide other objects</div>
<script>
$('#myDblClickObj').dblclick(function(){
    $('.textToHide').toggle();
});
</script>
```

Comment: The question doesn't have [jQuery] nor [JavaScript] tags.

Comment: @Oriol But there is no way for css to respond to double clicks. Recommending to use javascript/jquery is the only way. Unfortunately I don't think the OP truly wants to check for doubleclick.

Comment: @Andrew There is no way because CSS has no click notion, but you can fake it using other CSS notions. JavaScript is the sane way, but is not required. Posting a JS answer to a non-JS question is inappropriate.

Comment: @Oriol That would feel too hacky IMO. Javascript is much better. You don't need to stick strictly to that tags the OP uses, especially as they may not know about alternative methods that may do exactly what they want... maybe.. what do I know.

Comment: @Oriol feel free to show us the `pure css version`. I would like to know how to do that.

Comment: The question is too broad to post an answer, but you can get some ideas from [Toggle radio input using CSS only](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36162805/1529630)

Comment: I can add the tag if you're not against it, thank you for your help!

Comment: @FelippeDuarte There's actually two easy CSS/HTML versions. One using `:target` the other using `:checked +`. Both have since been posted as alternate answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple CSS way to do an "accordion" like behavior is with the CSS psuedo element [:target](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Atarget), which appears to have full support on current browsers (claim based on caniuse.com link given)

Basically `:target` works if the `#id` in the URL matches the ID of the element, like so:

```css
#text {
  transition: all linear 0.3s;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
#text:target {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a href="#text"> Click me to Show something </a>
<br />
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

This can be chained together with other links + items by tweaking the CSS and HTML a little.

```css
.special-section-name textarea {
  transition: all linear 0.3s;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
.special-section-name textarea:target {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 400px;
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class="special-section-name">
  <a href="#text1">Text 1</a>
  <br />
  <textarea id="text1"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="special-section-name">
  <a href="#text2">Text 2</a>
  <br />
  <textarea id="text2"></textarea>
</div>
```

If you want something to work by "double clicking" (clicking twice in a row), you're going to need a solution outside of CSS. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I've always liked the `:target` solution, felt really smart... but sadly it can't be nested like the `:checked +` solution. Still, +1 because static CSS/HTML

Comment: I stopped web development for a few years and when I came back CSS had all these cool tricks. When I found out about `:target` my jaw dropped.

Comment: Haha, you too? Think `+`, `~`, `>`, and `:not()` are my favorites... and don't get me started on all the Javascript things that were added from when I first dabbled in the mid 2000s. `document.querySelectorAll()` *swoon*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to support relics, you can do this entirely natively via CSS and HTML, by leveraging the `:checked` pseudoclass, the `+` selector, `label` tags, and `input type="radio"`.

```css
.accord-tog{ display:none; }
.accord-button{ display:block; }
.accord-content{ display:none; }
.accord-tog:checked + .accord-button + .accord-content{ display:block; }
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="accord$1" id="accord$1$1" class="accord-tog" />
<label for="accord$1$1" class="accord-button">Object 1</label>
<div class="accord-content">Text 1</div>
<input type="radio" name="accord$1" id="accord$1$2" class="accord-tog" />
<label for="accord$1$2" class="accord-button">Object 2</label>
<div class="accord-content">Text 2</div>
```

For a version that is more animated (and using `checkbox`es instead (thus why one doesn't close the other)), see [my answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36555859/5116879).

If you want to add close-on-click-again support, you'll need to use JS, sadly.

Comment: Nice. Very clean CSS solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly, but if you want a pure CSS Double-click implementation able to keep its current double-click-toggle state, I can show you my code. It uses 2 piled checkboxes and an animation. The first checkbox "starts to process a double-click", and the second one keeps the current toggled state.

In the snippet below (switch it better to fullpage), double-click the purple box. Than double-click it again. This code does not use JavaScript, it is CSS-only. Note also, that single-clicks do nothing, only double-clicks apply.

```css
@keyframes show1 {
  from {
    visibility: hidden;    
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;    
  }
}
@keyframes show2 {
  from {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@keyframes show3 {
  from {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@keyframes show4 {
  from {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}


#click, #click2 {
  display: none;
}

#single-click, #single-click2 {  
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;  
}

#single-click {
  animation: show1 200ms steps(1);
}

#click:checked ~ #single-click {
  animation: show2 200ms steps(1);
}

#single-click2 {
  animation: show3 200ms steps(1);
}

#click2:checked ~ #single-click2 {
  animation: show4 200ms steps(1);
}

p {
  opacity: 0;
}

#click:checked ~ p {
  opacity: 1;
}

/*Other stuff*/

body {
  /*tap support*/
  touch-action: none;  
}

.size {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
}

#single-click {
  background-color: #3366CC;
}

#single-click2 { 
  background-color: #6C36C3; 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>

  <body>
  <h1>CSS Double Click</h1>
  <h3>Double click detection without Javascript</h3>
  <h4>The enhanced version from https://codepen.io/ejsado/pen/EaFsy</h4>
  <div class="size">
    <input type="checkbox" id="click">
    <label id="single-click" for="click"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="click2">
    <label id="single-click2" for="click2"></label>    
    <div class="size"></div>
    <p class='menu-content'>You double clicked!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="size"></div>
  <h4>The colored box is a square checkbox label.</h4>
  <h4>It hides another square checkbox label of the same size (but of the different color).</h4>  
  <h4>When the top checkbox label is clicked, it triggers an animation which hides it for 200ms,</h4>
  <h4>and allows the bottom checkbox label to be checked.</h4>
  <h4>If the user is quick enough to check the bottom checkbox label, the success message appears.</h4>
  <h4>It is worth to note, that once the success message appeared, it can be removed only</h4>
  <h4>by either a new double-click or a page reload.</h4>
  </body>
</html>
```