# How to make a selected link active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

I can get to show a selected link, but when I click somewhere in the page, the highlight disappears. I'm also struggling to get the highlight to edges like the hover.

I've attached a piece of code and a picture for reference.

[image]

```
#sidebarContent a :ACTIVE, #sidebarContent a:FOCUS{
        background-color: Green;
        padding: 5px 10px; 
        /* margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto; */
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 120px;           
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to attach a class to your links; `:focus` and `:active` only persist so long as you are interacting with that element (like `:hover`).

Comment: As I see that this is tagged with jQuery, I would suggest you to chek out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738219/how-to-keep-active-css-style-after-clicking-an-element. When it comes to the highlight to edges-part, I think we might need some elaboration

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Gents!

Comment: @Anant, sorry my guy I didn't notice.

Comment: @Anant I can't see your answer anymore. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: @eldix_  you have accepted answer. so leave it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use angular application (you added this tag) - you can use `active` class to mark your current route instead of using `::focus` pseudo class.

```
  <a href="#/home" ng-class="{active: isActive('home')}">Home</a>
  <a href="#/about" ng-class="{active: isActive('about')}">About</a>
```

where:

```
$scope.isActive = function(path) {
    return $location.path() == '/' + path;
}
```

Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vadimb/2waujx3m/

Comment: if he is really using `angular-ui-bootstrap` then this is more good example. BTW +1  for jsfiddle link